# Is my textbook is giving the wrong answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$3=\frac{-4-y}{-3-x}$$

The answer says $y=3x+9$, but I am getting $y=3x+5$.
Please help.

Comment: Which of the following (if any) do you mean? $$3=-4-\frac{y}{-3}-x$$ $$3=\frac{-4-y}{-3-x}$$ $$3=-\frac{4-y}{-3}-x$$ $$3=\frac{-4-y}{-3}-x$$ $$3=-4-\frac{y}{-3-x}$$

Comment: If you want someone to tell you your mistake, you will have to show us your work.

Comment: You can easily check your answer by substituting for $y$ in the given equation. As it turns out, you are correct.

Comment: 9+3x=4+y, so y=3x+5.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$3 = \frac{4 + y}{3 + x}$$
$$9 + 3x = 4 + y$$
$$y = 5 + 3x$$

Hurray, you've found an erratum entry.